# How to play mp3 file chosen by the user?

Tags: android

I am trying to play a music file chosen by the user,the name of the music file stored in the database  depend on that I would play the music file from res/raw folder.

Thanks every one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried the media player ,it works but I have to type R.raw.filename

That's not true. The `MediaPlayer` class offers [several variants of the setDataSource method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29). You could for example pass it a `String` specifying a file path, or a `FileDescriptor` specifying a `FileInputStream`.

Setting the data source to a file named `test.mp3` on the external storage (typically an SD card) could be done in the following manner:
    `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test.mp3");`

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Thank you for your help,it works but this way makes me have to put the files in the sd card,is there a way to read the file from res/raw,or another way that can make me put the music files in the sd card while installing.

Comment: If you only want the user to be able to specify songs that come bundled with your application you could add the songs to your app's assets and then access them with `AssetFileDescriptor fd = getAssets().openFd("song.mp3"); mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor());`